# clearing markers after bounds changed, vue cookbook google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I have an issue about clearing markers after updating new bounds. New markers get added to the map but old markers stay still. It's a bit awkward because Vuex state renews every time when I post a request with new bounds...

I am giving the references for better understanding
[vue cookbook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/practical-use-of-scoped-slots.html)
and the cookbook's [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1o45zvxk0q?from-embed) (not my code but very much similar.)

**map-loader.vue**

Here I create the map and make request for **bounds** without a problem. And every time the map is dragged, I get the new markers in the new array in Vuex.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="google-map" ref="googleMap"></div>
        <template v-if="Boolean(this.google) && Boolean(this.map)">
            <slot
                :google="google"
                :map="map"
            />
        </template>       
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import GoogleMapsApiLoader from 'google-maps-api-loader'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
    props: {
        mapConfig: Object,
        apiKey: String,
        info_and_center: Function,
    },

    data() {
        return {
            google: null,
            map: null
        }
    },

    async mounted() {
        const googleMapApi = await GoogleMapsApiLoader({
            apiKey: this.apiKey
        })
        this.google = googleMapApi
        this.initializeMap()
    },
    watch:{
        mapConfig(old_ad, new_ad){
            this.initializeMap()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        initializeMap() {
            const mapContainer = this.$refs.googleMap
            this.map = new this.google.maps.Map(
                mapContainer, this.mapConfig
            )     

            let self = this;

            this.google.maps.event.addListener((this.map), 'idle', function(event) {
                self.get_markers();
            });
        },
        get_markers(){
            let bounds = this.map.getBounds();
            let south_west = bounds.getSouthWest();
            let north_east = bounds.getNorthEast();

            let payload = {
                "from_lat": south_west.lat(),
                "to_lat": north_east.lat(),
                "from_lng": south_west.lng(),
                "to_lng": north_east.lng(),
            }
            
            // manually clearing the array of markers
            this.$store.state.project.projects = []
            console.log(this.get_projects)
            // it's cleared

            this.$store.dispatch("load_projects_by_coords", payload)
        },
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            "get_projects"
        ])
    }
}
</script>
```

### UPDATED

Normally I don't need to do that, but inside the `get_markers()` I wrote code to clear `get_projects` before new `dispatch` but still, old markers stay still.

**map.vue**

```
<template>
    <GoogleMapLoader
        :mapConfig="mapConfig"
        apiKey="my_key"
    >
        <template slot-scope="{ google, map}">
            <GoogleMapMarker
                v-for="marker in get_projects"
                :key="marker.id"
                :marker="marker"
                :google="google"
                :map="map"
            />
        </template>
    </GoogleMapLoader>
</template>
<script>
import GoogleMapLoader from './google-map-loader'
import GoogleMapMarker from './google-map-marker'
import { mapSettings } from './helpers/map-setting'
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
    components: {
        GoogleMapLoader,
        GoogleMapMarker,
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            "get_projects",
            "get_search_address_lat",
            "get_search_address_lng",
        ]),
        mapConfig () {
            return {
                ...mapSettings,
                center: this.mapCenter
            }
        },
        mapCenter () {
            return {lat: this.get_search_address_lat, lng: this.get_search_address_lng}
        },
    },
}
```

As you see, I am iterating over the new markers inside the `get_projects` without any problem. But old markers stay still, although when I `console.log(this.get_projects)` only new markers are in there after the bounds have changed. So the question is *How can I update the map with the new markers?*

**markers.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        google: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        map: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        marker: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
    },
    mounted() {

        let marker = new this.google.maps.Marker({
            position: this.marker,
            marker: this.marker,
            map: this.map,
        })

        var contentString = "test";

        var infowindow = new this.google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        this.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            this.map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
        });
    },
    render(){},
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not worked with this API before. But I see that removing markers is not covered in the cookbook link you posted. What I think is happening is that you are registering a new marker on mounted, which is fine of course, but you're not removing it when the component is destroyed.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) says to use `setMap` on the `Marker` to null, in order to remove it. So maybe if you kept the reference to the marker created in the `mounted` hook, you can remove it in the `beforeDestroy` hook.

*GoogleMapMarker.vue*

```
  data: () => ({
    mapMarker: null
  }),

  mounted() {
    const { Marker } = this.google.maps;

    this.mapMarker = new Marker({
      position: this.marker.position,
      marker: this.marker,
      map: this.map,
      icon: POINT_MARKER_ICON_CONFIG
    });
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    this.mapMarker.setMap(null);
  },
```

ps. `let self = this;` is unnecessary.

```
let self = this;

this.google.maps.event.addListener((this.map), 'idle', function(event) {
    self.get_markers();
});
```

Anonymous function:

```
this.google.maps.event.addListener((this.map), 'idle', event => {
    this.get_markers();
});
```

Comment: thank you for answering me back. `beforeDestroy` is solved the problem!! and thank you for pointing out the `self` part.

Comment: Glad I could help. Are you sure the `self = this` error is not resolved when using an anonymous function?

Comment: oh, it resolved. no problem...  thank you for pointing that out as well.